# AJAX Update Panel Doesn't Work. Please help me finding where am I wrong...?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, gridview, updatepanel

--------------Gridviews DataBound Event -----------------

```
protected void grdShowCallingList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (grdShowCallingList.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
      foreach (GridViewRow row in grdShowCallingList.Rows)
        {
           LinkButton lnkCallHistorySummary = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("lnkCallHistorySummary");
            lnkCallHistorySummary.OnClientClick = "return getCallHistroySummary('" + lblPersonID.Text + "','" + lblDomainID.Text + "');";
        }
    }
}
```

-------------Javascript Event To invoke trigger-------

```
function getCallHistroySummary(PID,DID)
{
document.getElementById("ctl00_cphContent_hfCHS").value = PID + "|" + DID;
document.getElementById("ctl00_cphContent_btnTrgCHS1").click();
return false;

}
function btnTrgCHS1Click() {
document.getElementById("ctl00_cphContent_btnTrgCHS_server").click();
return false;
}
```

-------------Button To Be Triggered-------------

```
//------------Modal Popup Starts-------------
<div ID="pnlCallSumHistory" runat="server"  style="overflow: scroll; width: 710px; height: 400px;">
<asp:Button ID="btnTrgCHS_server" runat="server" OnClick="btnTrgCHS_Click" style="display:none;" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnlCallHistory" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Literal ID="ltrCallHistory" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers >
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnTrgCHS_server" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

</div>
//------------Modal Popup Panel Ends-------------
<asp:Button ID="btnTrgCHS1" runat="server"  style="display:none;"         onclientclick="btnTrgCHS1Click();"  />
```

I am unable to fire the Trigger Event Associated with **btnTrgCHS_server** *Click* Event...

Comment: where is the **btnTrgCHS_server** button

Comment: @sharad Sorry, for not including that here. I have added it in the codes now. It is placed outside the panel that will be used as modal popup.

Comment: Are you using jQuery dialogs for your Modal popup? They have some notorious problems.

Comment: No, its AJAX ModalPopupExtender

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `btnTrgCHS_server` is a control nested within a `GridView` The reason it's not firing is because the `UpdatePanel` will do a `FindControl()` on the page to look for `btnTrgCHS_server`.  The `FindControl()` method won't look at nested controls.

The most simple thing to do would be to wrap another `UpdatePanel` around the `GridView` as follows:

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanelGridView" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>

  <%-- other code etc --%>

  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnlCallHistory" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Literal ID="ltrCallHistory" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

`ChildrenAsTriggers` will mean that any form submission within the panel will cause an AJAX postback.

The `UpdateMode` of `Always` will need to be set on the `UpdatePanel` that surrounds your `Literal` so that it will update when `updPanelGridView` fires the AJAX postback.

The only thing to bear in mind is that this will *always* update `updPanelGridView`.

I'm also not sure of what exactly is in your `GridView`, so it's possible that it could cause a conflict.

If that happens, you could try try wrapping your Button that's in the `GridView` in an `UpdatePanel` - this may cause less issues

NB - this will also most likely cause the IDs of `btnTrgCHS1` to change, so you may need to update the JavaScript which calls the `click()` event to the new ID.

**EDIT**

From looking at the updated question/discussion on other answers I think I know the problem.  You'll need to amend 2 things:

1 - Change the `ControlID` in the `Triggers` section to point at the button itself - not the server method you wish to call.

i.e.

```
<Triggers >
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnTrgCHS" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

2 - Change the button to include an `OnClick` - you haven't defined what server-side method should be called when the button is clicked.  This means that the AJAX won't know which method to use when it posts back.

i.e.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTrgCHS1" OnClick="btnTrgCHS1_server" runat="server"  style="display:none;"         onclientclick="btnTrgCHS1Click();"  />
```

Comment: It is not in gridview, but it is in a Modal popup defined out of it. The Linkbutton `lnkCallHistorySummary` is in gridview and the same is bound with javascript's `getCallHistroySummary` event to click on the trigger of update panel `btnTrgCHS_server` that is again present out of the gridview and the modal popup as well.

Comment: Do you mean the button is within a `ModalPopup` control?  In which case the same theory still applies - the `Trigger` section can't find a control that's nested within another control.

Comment: No, the logic that I have used is, I had to use same popup for several results of gridview rows. The panel in which the update panel exists, has been wrapped up with a Ajax Modal Popup Extender. When someone clicks the link of gridview, a javascript method is called and will be passed with 2 parameters. These 2 parameters will be used to fetch data from the server and the result is passed to the update panel. This is done by clicking `btnTrgCHS_server` from the javascript at the same time which is present outside the ₹ModalPopup₹. But, here is the problem, the trigger is no firing at all.

Comment: I think I may have figured out the issue - I've updated my answer with extra suggestions at the end - do you think that could be the cause?

Comment: @Cyberpks - did that solve your issue?  If so, it would be great to mark the question as answered.  If not, it would be useful for everyone else to know how you resolved the issue by posting the answer yourself and marking it as answered :)

Comment: Other People and @tristankoffee- Thanks, for your support, but I haven't been able to solve the issue yet. I guess it is something else that is making the problem. For now, I have changed the structure and the functionality for my page totally, so that the data is populated in the `Grid_bound` event and shown in a Custom tool tip. But, it seems as if the problem is somewhere else as even after change in codes one of my dropdown in the same update panel is not making a postback. I'll try to figure out...

Answer (score 0):

Do not hardcode your dynamically generated IDs. These will change as you add container controls.

Use the [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property instead to get the client side id generated by asp.net.

```
function getCallHistroySummary(PID,DID){
  document.getElementById("<%=hfCHS.ClientID%>").value = PID + "|" + DID;
  document.getElementById("<%=btnTrgCHS_server.ClientID%>").click();
  return false;
}
```

Your ClientIDs do seem to be wrong. Correct them and check

Comment: Can you please explain it. Do I have to use the same javascript as given by you, or something else is required alongwith it? I am getting a Javascript Error ->*TypeError: document.getElementById("<%=hfCHS.ClientID%>") is null.*

Comment: `CliendID` is available on the control in an aspx page. This code must be on an aspx page that has the controls `hfCHS` and `btnTrgCHS_server`

Comment: I think `ClientID` must be a static property and should be managed by the server itself. Please don't mind, but, in my case it has nothing to do with that. I can see that the javascript function is being called, as I can invoke an alert box from the same, and I have also cross checked it with firebug, the Controls have same ID's, that I have used, but my problem is that I can't fire the `btnTrgCHS_server` Click Event from the javascript...

Answer (score 0):

If thats the case you need to manually trigger the postback using __doPostback() from the javascript.

Then in the Page_Load() find the element that postedback.. If the ID of the button is the ID you are looking for then call the event with null arguments.. This should solve  your problem..

```
btnTrgCHS1Click(null,null)
```

And the event should be OnClick instead of onClientClick()